# PHP date conversion mm/dd/yy to yyyy/mm/dd -error

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime

My input date format is dd/mm/yy. I am using the following code to convert it into yyyy-mm-dd.

```
    $cal_date= $fileop[1];
    $date = str_replace('/', '-', $cal_date);
    $invdate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));
```

Result i got is 24/10/13-->2024-10-13. Can anyone correct me.

Here two conversions 2digit year to 4 digit year 
and /replaced by -dash

Comment: `strtotime()` has a [strict list of formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) that it will understand, and `dd-mm-y` or `dd/mm/y` are not part of that list.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another way - [See The Demo Here](http://codepad.org/U6QaenaO)

```
<?php

$date= "02/05/2013"; //dd/mm/yy
$dd=substr($date, 0, 2);
$mm=substr($date, 3, 2);
$yy=substr($date, 6, 4);

echo $yy."/".$mm."/".$dd; // yyyy-mm-dd.

?>
```

Comment: it works. but How can i convert two digit yr to 4 digit yr

Comment: make it as the answer

Answer (score 3):

Using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object might be better

```
try{
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y',$cal_date);
   $invdate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage(); // or
   print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());
}
```

Comment: @Anthony either function will work. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php

Comment: One is a function, the other is a method. They both point to the same thing, but it's more clear that it's using the class when you use the method. And you had an error in your code I fixed.

Comment: This code returns the fatal error  Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

Comment: Except that, as the title states, the current format is m/d/Y.

Comment: And the text of the post says d/m/Y. Talk about confusing. :/

Comment: @aynber I am getting an error - Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

Comment: @Indra Something failed somewhere, then. I updated the code with how to get the error message.

Comment: @aynber it doesnt work

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: this is the error i got.....Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

Comment: Even with the try block?

Comment: Yes aynber. i am working on it for more than 3 hrs

Comment: Actually this code---$invdate = date_format(date_create_from_format('d/m/y', $fileop[1]), 'Y-m-d');--- returns required results as well as an error...."date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in"

Comment: Add `print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors());` right after the createFromFormat line, and see if it prints anything out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y',$cal_date);
$break = explode("/", $date);
$yearComp = $break[2];
if($yearComp < 70)
    $invdate = $date->format('Y-m-d'); 
else {
    // code that would add 100 years to the date generated }
```

But just know that 69 would print out 2069 but 70 would be 1970. If you won't get to 70, then this should be fine

Comment: whats the difference between your code and my code

Comment: If it is not working it means $fileop[1] is not returning the correct thing.

Comment: $fileop[1] is 24/10/13. Here 13 is a two digit yr.

Answer (score -1):

In one shoot:

```
$invdate = date_format(date_create_from_format('m/d/y', $fileop[1]), 'Y-m-d');
```

If you are not confident with the imput date format:

```
if ($invdate = date_create_from_format('m/d/y', $fileop[1])) {
    $invdate = date_format($invdate, 'Y-m-d'); //date format yyyy-mm-dd
} else {
    echo "ERROR: '{$fileop[1]}' has not the date format mm/dd/yy";
}
```

Comment: Excellent. It works but returns  an error "date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in"

Comment: That is because you are using a different date format than the expected. Consider fix your question example, so it must use the same date format specified at the question title.